# Understanding linear linked list

Tags: data-structures, recursion

I have some problems understanding the linear linked list data structure. This is how I define a list element:

```
class Node{
    Object data;
    Node link;

    public Node(Object pData, Node pLink){
        this.data = pData;
        this.link = pLink;
    }
}
```

To keep it simple we say that a list are linked nodes so we do not need to define a class list (recursion principle).

My problem is that I am really confused in understanding how nodes are connected, more precisely the sequence of the nodes when we connect them.

```
Node n1 = new Node(new Integer(2), null);
Node n2 = new Node(new Integer(1), n1);
```

What is link? Is it the previous or the next element? Any other suggestions to help me understanding this data structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this drawing will help you to understand.

[image]

(Be aware that arrows are references NOT pointers for Java)

The "list" will be a reference to the very first node.

Answer (score 4):

`link` is a reference to the next Node in the list.

So you would start at the first node in the list, `n1`, which you'd have a direct reference to.  To get the second node in the list, you'd reference `n1.link`.

To iterate over the list, you would have to have some starting point, such as `n1`, then repeatedly reference `link`:

```
Node n = n1;
while (n != null) {
    println(n.data);
    n = n.link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a singly-linked list, it's "next".

It looks like Java, even though you haven't tagged it as such.  If that's true, consider using generics:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    T value;
    Node<T> next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

First, about the "is this the previous or the next element": it depends on your data structure. Usually it is the next element.

Second, I'd recommend using a pointer or a reference. (And your C++ syntax is incorrect: `this` is a pointer, and the `new` operator also returns a pointer. Not sure if you use C++ though, since you didn't specify a lanugage.)

So for example:

```
class Node {
    Object data;
public:
    Node *next;

    Node (Object pData, Node *pLink) {
        this->data = pData;
        this->next = pLink;
    }
}
```

This would be a more valid structure. Then you could do:

```
Node *n3 = new Node(new Integer(2), null);
Node *n2 = new Node(new Integer(1), n1);
Node *n1 = new Node(new Integer(3), n2);
```

or simply

```
Node *n1 = new Node(new Integer(3), new Node(new Integer(1), new Node(new Integer(2), NULL)));
```

Then you could iterate through the list as follows:

```
for (Node *current = n1; current != NULL; current = current->next)
{
    // do something with the current element
}
```

I hope this helps!

---

If you use a modern language, there are already premade linked list structures in C++'s stl, in .NET it's in System.Collections.Generic and I'm sure there is also a Java counterpart.

Comment: Yes, there's a Java List interface and a LinkedList implementation for it.  I'm guessing the question is still pertinent because this is a student looking to understand the implementation details.